# Wie kann man zwischen AUCH[Adverb] und AUCH[Modalpartikel] unterscheiden?

Tags: modal-particle

Mir fällt es immer schwer, zwischen *auch* [Adverb] und *auch* [Modalpartikel] zu unterscheiden. Zum Beispiel, ziehen wir mal diesen Satz aus dem Duden in Betracht:

*"Darf er das auch tun?"*

Ohne den obengenannten Satz zu hören, hat man keine Ahnung von der Betonung. Also wenn mir beim Lesen solche Sätze begegnen, da weiß ich nicht, was damit gemeint ist, nämlich: (Im Englischen!)

1º) Is he allowed to do that too? (besides other things)
2º) Is he really allowed to do that? (showing doubt, uncertainty)

Kann der Satzbau (bzw. Wortstellung) darauf hinweisen, was damit gemeint wird?

Ich bedanke mich im voraus für Eure Antworten!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Du kannst es am Hingeschriebenen oft nicht unterscheiden. In deinem Beispiel hilft nur die Betonung im Satz.

- Modalpartikel sind grundsätzlich unbetont.

> Darf er das **auch** tun?

Hier ist **auch** ganz offensichtlich ein Adverb.

> **Darf** er das auch tun?
>
> Darf **er** das auch tun?
>
> Darf er **das** auch tun?
>
> Darf er das auch **tun**?

Hier ist *auch* hingegen ein Modalpartikel.

---

Adverben wie *auch* sind manchmal ein qualifizierendes Element für das Subjekt oder ein Objekt. In diesem Fall ist es schon anhand des Niedergeschriebenen klar, dass dieser Satzteil betont werden muss:

> Darf **auch er** das tun?
>
> Darf er **auch das** tun?

---

Im Grunde genommen ist es aber so, dass, wenn man den Unterschied im Niedergeschriebenen auch anhand des vorherigen Kontextes nicht erkennen kann, dies **Absicht** ist. Ein Stilmittel. Es klärt sich dann meist ein paar Sätze später auf.